# On showing the commutativity of the square diagram between vector spaces and their double duals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A, B$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over the field $\mathbb{K}$, and $T \in \mathcal{L}(A, B)$ be an arbitrary linear map. Let $f:A \to A^{**}$ and $g:B \to B^{**}$ be the natural isomorphisms between the vector spaces $A, B$ and their double dual spaces. We'd like to show that $T^{**} \circ f = g \circ T$, where $T^{**}:A^{**}\to B^{**}$. Currently I am stuck, with the following reasoning:

Let $a \in A$ be arbitrary. Then $(T^{**}\circ f)(a) = T^{**}(f(a)) \in B^{**}$, so by bijectivity of $g$, for an unique $b = g^{-1}((T^{**}\circ f)(a))$ we have that $(T^{**}\circ f)(a) = g(b)$. Since $b \in B$, for some $a' \in A: T(a') = b$, so that $g(b) = g(T(a')) = (g \circ T)(a')$. Thus $(T^{**}\circ f)(a) = (g \circ T)(a')$

Here's where I am stuck: How do I argue that $a' = a$? We know for sure that $f$ and $g$ are injective and surjective, but as far as I know, we don't have any information on $A$.

Edit: $T^{**}$ is defined to be: $T^{**}(\gamma) = \gamma(T^*), \gamma \in A^{**}$ where $T^*:B^* \to A^*, T^*(\tau) = \tau(T), \tau \in B^*$

Comment: What is your definition of $T^{\ast\ast}?$

Comment: @F_M_ $T^{**}$ is defined to be: $T^{**}(\gamma) = \gamma(T^*), \gamma \in A^{**}$ where $T^*:B^* \to A^*, T^*(\tau) = \tau(T), \tau \in B^*$. So effectively $T^{**}$ is the double transpose of $T$ with the linear mappings. Here $\gamma$ and $\tau$ are arbitrary.

Comment: With $\tau(T), \tau \in B^\ast$ you mean $\tau \circ T?$

Comment: Let $a\in A$ and $\varphi\in B^\ast$. Using the definitions of $f,g,T^{\ast\ast}$, compute both $(g\circ T)(a)(\varphi)$ and $(T^{\ast\ast}\circ f)(a)(\varphi)$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway: in your reasoning, the existence of $a^\prime \in A$ such that $T(a^\prime) = b$ might fail if $T$ is not bijective. And as Stefan Albrecht says, check that both $T^{\ast\ast} \circ f$ and $g\circ T$ are the same elements in $B^{\ast \ast}$ by looking what they do with $\phi \in B^\ast.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in A$ and $\phi \in B^{\ast}.$ On the one hand we have
\begin{align*}
\left(T^{\ast\ast}\circ f\right)(a)(\phi) &= \left(f(a)\circ T^{\ast}\right)(\phi) \\
&= f(a)\left(T^{\ast}(\phi)\right) \\
&= f(a)\left( \phi\circ T\right)\\
&= (\phi \circ T)(a)\\
&= \phi(T(a)).
\end{align*}
On the other hand
\begin{align*}
\left(g\circ T\right)(a)(\phi) &= \left(g(T(a)\right)(\phi) \\
&= \phi(T(a)).
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you justify the transitions $f(a)(\phi \circ T) = (\phi \circ T)(a)$ and $(g(T(a))(\phi) = \phi(T(a))$? This is something I have been thinking about quite a while now, as once we've transitioned to $B^{**}$ by $f(a)(\phi \circ T)$ we have that the lhs element of the composition is a function from $A^{**}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the rhs element is a function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note that for $a\in A$ we have $f(a)\in A^{\ast\ast}.$ Since $f$ is the natural isomorphism, $f(a)$ is just evaluation at $a$, i.e. for $\psi \in A^{\ast}$ we have $(f(a))(\psi) = \psi(a).$ The same holds for $g$ it makes the association of $b \in B$ with the evaluation at $b,$ that is for $\phi \in B^\ast$ we have $(g(b))(\phi) = \phi(b).$ I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it sure does! I am new to the functional analysis side of linear algebra, so I was a bit lost with the notation/semantic side of things.